# Inherit test Dagger component from main test Dagger Component with changes

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a next component in main code `AppComponent.`kt`

```
  @ApllicationScope  
    @Component(
       modules = [
       SomeClass::class,
       SomeClass2::class,
       SomeClass2::class,
       ....
       ]
    }
```

In test package i have `TestAppComponent.kt`, which have similiar code instead SomeClass2::java.class is replaced with TestSomeClass2::java.class and have additional  `OnlyTestClass::class` module

```
  @ApllicationScope  
    @Component(
       modules = [
       SomeClass::class,
       TestSomeClass2::class,
       SomeClass2::class,
       OnlyTestClass::.class
       ....
       ]
    }
```

So i am in situation where any changes in main `AppComponent.kt` should be reflected in `TestAppComponent.kt` - i should manually change it, and it's taking a time to find what's goes wrong during tests in `TestAppComponent.kt` when other person add/remove component

Is there a way to inherit test component from the main, but in the same time replace `SomeClass2::class` with it testing variant and add `OnlyTestClass::class` ?

Thanks in advance.